# Submit and save dynamically changed fields in form with Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I have a form. New fields to this form can be added, existing fields can be edited by entering different values and already existing fields can be deleted, all this dynamically with jQuery.

**Currently my solution is:** when submitting the form I make foreach on posted data and depends on posted values I decide which item should be created(by creating new object, setting attributes, and then save() - SQL insert statement), which should be updated(by finding existing item, setting new attributes, and then save() - SQL update statement) and which deleted(by comparing all the items before editing with the items after clients interaction and remove unnecessary items with SQL delete).

I am searching for better solution of this problem because the code with my solution is not so beautiful. I thought that save() on some object or collection would do the job...am i right?

**Note:** Deleting all the items first and then creating them as new doesn't work for me as submitted values are foreign keys to another tables so they could not be deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Eloquent? `save()` should detect if the record will be created or updated.

Answer (score 0):

Do your fields have relationships to each other? I am assuming that they do because you are using the same form to post data. If so, you need to simplify your code by defining the relationships between the fields using the docs:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

If your fields do not have any relationships to each other then they should not be posted together. If this is not helpful, maybe post your code so you can get a better answer.